# c# how to set several combobox column in datagridview

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datagridview, combobox

I have been able to make one existing column combo box column in the datagridview, how do I do it for several columns? Also how do I add existing distinct records in the combobox items? The user will be able to either choose value from combobox item or write their own. So far my code is:

```
            dgvLoadTable.DataSource = null;
            var context = new CadAdminEntities();
            var TableName = cboSelectTable.Text.ToString();
            var rawData = context.GetType().GetProperty(TableName).GetValue(context, null);
            var truncatedData = ((IQueryable<object>)rawData).Take(0);
            var source = new BindingSource { DataSource = truncatedData };
            dgvLoadTable.DataSource = source;
            dgvLoadTable.ReadOnly = false;
            dgvLoadTable.AllowUserToAddRows = true;

            DataGridViewComboBoxCell dgvCol = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();

            for (int row= 0; row < dgvLoadTable.Rows.Count; row++)
            {
             for (int col = 0; col < dgvLoadTable.Columns.Count; col++)
                   {
                       if(col==2||col==4)
                       this.dgvLoadTable[col,row] = dgvCol;
                 //This part throws error, as there is only one combobox
                   }
            }

            dgvLoadTable.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easy to fix:

```
this.dgvLoadTable[col, row] = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
```

will create a fresh ComboBoxCell for each case.

You can delete the line

```
DataGridViewComboBoxCell dgvCol = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
```

Note that since you have a Databound DGV and the Columns were probably created automatically, you should keep in mind, that often one needs to switch off that automatism and create all column manually before setting the DataSource..